# How can I click a web element for a 3rd party page?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have an Ecommerce website and on one page there is a button named *Place Order*. When I click on the *Place Order* button, then it allows me to open a new window named *Paypal*. I need to stay on the same tab without opening the new window. After that I need to click on the element for that *Paypal* page.
How can I do this?

[image: Screenshot]

My code is as follows:

```
String parent_handle= driver.getWindowHandle();
System.out.println(parent_handle);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='co-place-order-area']/div[2]/div[3]/div/button")).click();

new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(1));
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
System.out.println(handles);
for(String handle1:handles)
    if(!parent_handle.equals(handle1))
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(handle1);
        System.out.println(handle1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about java but in C# you would use PopupWindowFinder class

```
        var target = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='co-place-order-area']/div[2]/div[3]/div/button"));

        PopupWindowFinder finder = new PopupWindowFinder(driver);
        var parent = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
        string newHandle = finder.Click(target);
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(newHandle);
```

Then after you deal with the new window you can switch back to the parent window.

Comment: Agree. But I m not able to click on any element  of Paypal page.

Comment: Did you verify you can get to its window handle?